# A test problem about algebraic integers in complex field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra

In a recent algebraic test, I meet this problem:

> Let R be the ring of algebraic integers in C, K is the field of algebraic numbers in C. Let a be an element of K such that the ring R[a] is contained in an R-submodule M of K and M is a finitely generated R-module. Prove that a is an element of R.

I spent much time on it and still failed  to solve it. If M is R[a]-module such that a*M is in M, then we just use Nakayama lemma. But we can't do this now and R is not noetherian... So how to prove it? (Or maybe it is a typo? I doubt that maybe this is a typo in the test?)

Comment: Take a set $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ of generators for M over R, and write $a = c_1 e_1 + \cdots + c_n e_n, c_i \in R$.  Then replace the huge objects $R$, and $M$ with the much smaller objects $R' = Z[c_1, \ldots, c_n],  M' = R'[e_1, \ldots, e_n]$.  Now all the necessary relations still work and things are notherian, and $a \in R'$ implies $a \in R$.

Comment: I'm sorry that I still feel confused. Why the necessary relations still work? Why R'[a] is contained in a finitely generated R' module?(M' is a finitely generated R' algebra, not a f.g. R' module).  Can you expain it in a more detail way?Thanks. @LanceSackless

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstand you? Do you mean that M' is a R' module generated by this n elements? But if so, R'[a] may not lie in M'.... @LanceSackless